# ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#to_date returns wrong date

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I want date part from an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. I used `to_date` function for that but it returns date one day earlier.

For example, if datetime is `2012-04-11 09:05:00 UTC`, and if I call `to_date` then it returns `2012-04-10` but `2012-04-11`.

Also I am not using specific timezone (defaults to UTC)

The application is running on `Ruby 1.8.7` and `Rails 3.0.2`

Can anyone please tell me why it gives wrong date? Also please suggest me if there is better way to get date (instance of `Date`) part from given `DateTime` (instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`)

**EDIT** :
someone is also facing same issue here http://pastebin.com/sn8ExZiQ

**NOTE** : `Time.zone` returns `'UTC'`

Comment: What is the value of Time.zone ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Time.zone return UTC

Comment: what's the output of `zone` of the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object you're calling `to_date` on?

Comment: @shime it returns `#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0xb7565fb0 @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @utc_offset=nil, @name="UTC", @current_period=nil> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Jignesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936494/jignesh). Here I am sharing your findings and solutions.

There may be some gem that is overriding `to_date` implementation and it may be implemented incorrectly and this overridden version might be getting called.

In my case the culprit was `ruby-units` gem

**Root Cause** : `ruby-units` gem included in the application’s Gemfile

**Problem Analysis** :

**Gemfile**

```
# Ruby-units overrides String class #to method, hence placed before Rails
gem "ruby-units" # Loads first and then rails is loaded

gem "rails", "3.0.11"

..
..
```

**time.rb file (ruby-units gem codebase)**

```
..
..

unless Time.instance_methods.include?(:to_date)
    # :nocov_19:
    # @return [Date]
    def to_date
     x=(Date.civil(1970,1,1)+((self.to_f+self.gmt_offset)/86400.0)-0.5)
     Date.civil(x.year, x.month, x.day)
    end
    # :nocov_19:
end

..
..
```

Lets say that current time in `UTC` time-zone is
`Wed, 11 Apr 2012 10:12:17 UTC +00:00` represented by a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`
instance.
From the rails application when we execute `<TimeWithZone>.to_date` it returns
a date `2012-04-10` which is incorrect.

The culprit involved in above incorrect behavior is the implementation of `to_date` method
provided by `ruby-units` gem

Below is a sample program to demonstrate the above incorrect behaviour. The `to_date` method is identical to one implemented by `ruby-units` gem, except that an argument is added to the method namely `date_time` and the `self` in the implementation is replaced by the argument
'date_time'.

Sample Ruby Program to confirm the findings above:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'

class TestDT
 def to_date(date_time)
     #x=(Date.civil(1970,1,1)+((self.to_f+self.gmt_offset)/86400.0)-0.5)
     x=(Date.civil(1970,1,1)+((date_time.to_f+date_time.gmt_offset)/86400.0)-0.5)
     Date.civil(x.year, x.month, x.day)
 end
end

tdt = TestDT.new
utc_time = Time.now.in_time_zone('UTC')
puts tdt.to_date(utc_time)
```

Output (date at the time of writing this was Wed, `11 Apr 2012 08:35:12 UTC +00:00`):

```
$ ruby test_date_time.rb
2012-04-10
```

**Solution:**

1. Remove the `ruby-units` gem from the `Gemfile` or load it after rails gem
2. Workaround: Instead of executing `datetime.to_date` , use `datetime.to_s.to_date`