# Really odd issues with Time when it used within a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, heroku

There is a page in my Rails-app where tours should be displayed so that the start_date field is equal to tomorrow's date (in GMT+00)

I use default timezone in application.rb

```
# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record ...
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

**However there in is a problem.  Instead of the page displaying tour dates starting  from tomorrow, I see dates from today and even yesterday.**

I put to the page the following information:

```
Time.zone                (GMT+00:00) UTC
Date.today_local_zone    2013-11-20
Date.today               2013-11-20
Time.now                 2013-11-20 00:48:21 +0000
```

Code in my controller:

```
puts "... #{ Tour.upcoming.order('start_date ASC').to_sql }"
@tours = Tour.upcoming.order('start_date ASC')
```

And the scope in Tour model

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :start_date, :title
  scope :upcoming, where('tours.start_date > ?', Date.today_local_zone)
end
```

Briefly about my today_local_zone method:

```
class Date
  def self.today_local_zone
    Time.zone.now.to_date
  end
end
```

**Here is a line from my logs (the date the query is different from the date in the logs)**

```
2013-11-20T00:48:21.178380+00:00 app[web.1]: ... SELECT "tours".* FROM "tours"  WHERE (tours.start_date > '2013-11-19') ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

- After `heroku restart` or deploy dates besome correct
- In heroku console `heroku run rails c` all dates are correct too
- I decided to start another application from scratch and to deploy in on heroku. And result remained the same.
- I ping this page every 5 minutes with pingdom. Date become correct after hour or two or even 23 after midnight. i.e. value of lag is different each day.

**UPD:**

I tried to log value of `Time.zone.now.to_s.to_date`. It's value is correct.

Please also look at [my gist](http://gist.github.com/pyeremenko/7559892) with:

- Gemfile
- Screenshot of webpage, including all values and text of generated query

Comment: What is the type of your start_date column?  Does your ping page always show a Time.zone of UTC?  Does the Time.now always show '+0000', or does it display other offsets

Comment: 1) Type of start_date is date.  
2) Yes. 
3) Yes, Time.now always shows '+0000'

Comment: The comments here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099698/activesupporttimewithzoneto-date-returns-wrong-date - might be relevant.  Do you have any gems that may be overriding to_date?  What happens if you change your Date#local_time_zone method to use `Time.zone.now.to_s.to_date` ?

Comment: Here is my Gemfile https://gist.github.com/pyeremenko/7559892 . I created a simple application to reproduce the error. So Gemfile is pretty simple and as I think, haven't any gems that may change behavior of dates.

Comment: Nothing obvious in the Gemfile.  Have you tried the `to_s` option I suggested above?

Comment: Yes, I tried `Time.zone.now.to_s.to_date`, the value is correct. Please, look at the gist, I've updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this on first review.  The problem is in your scope statement:

```
scope :upcoming, where('tours.start_date > ?', Date.today_local_zone)
```

This definition is wrong.  It loads Date.today_local_zone when the class is loaded.  You need to wrap it in a Proc.  So it should be:

```
scope :upcoming, lambda { where('tours.start_date > ?', Date.today_local_zone) }
```

which ensures that Date.today_local_zone is executed each time the scope is used.